# Why are Angular Material tooltips breaking my unit tests?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, angular-material2

I have the following unit test file, which is a duplicate of a working file from another similar component and not too far from boilerplate Angular CLI output:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Http, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

import { PageHeaderComponent } from './page-header.component';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { PreloadService } from '../preload.service';

describe('PageHeaderComponent', () => {
    let component: PageHeaderComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<PageHeaderComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [PageHeaderComponent],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: Http,
                    deps: [MockBackend]
                },
                PreloadService,
                UserService
            ],
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PageHeaderComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

However, this one fails due to a problem with [mdTooltip](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview). It results in this error:

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) PageHeaderComponent should be created FAILED
>
> Error: Template parse errors:
>           Can't bind to 'mdTooltipDisabled' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. ("fxLayoutAlign="start center" class="text-medium">
>                       ][mdTooltipDisabled]="showHeaderTooltip">
>                           view_agenda 
>                       ][mdTooltipDisabled]="showHeaderTooltip">
>                           directions 
>                       ][mdTooltipDisabled]="showHeaderTooltip" href="{{environment?.search_url}}">
>                           http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js (line 25078)
>           parse@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:25078:72
>           _compileTemplate@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:39124:44
>   
> ....

Here's an example of the markup:

```
<button md-button mdTooltip="Topics" [mdTooltipDisabled]="showHeaderTooltip">
    <md-icon>view_agenda</md-icon> <span fxShow.xs="false">Topics</span>
</button>
```

Here is my version table:

```
@angular/cli: 1.1.2
node: 6.11.0
os: linux x64
@angular/animations: 4.2.3
@angular/common: 4.2.3
@angular/compiler: 4.2.3
@angular/core: 4.2.3
@angular/forms: 4.2.3
@angular/http: 4.2.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.2.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.3
@angular/router: 4.2.3
@angular/cli: 1.1.2
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.3
@angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/language-service: 4.2.3
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.7
```

What do I need to provide to mock or otherwise handle the mdTooltip service, which apparently involves an observable?

Update: Apparently this occurs for other AM services as well, such as `mdMenuTriggerFor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2478

"Fixed by importing ‘**MaterialModule**’ to TestBed.configureTestingModule in failing spec."

As in:

```
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [PageHeaderComponent],
        providers: [
            {
                imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]), MaterialModule],
                provide: Http,
                deps: [MockBackend]
            },
            PreloadService,
            UserService
        ],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    });
```

Comment: I think the answer might be outdated at this point though the intent is still correct.  I got this working by importing MatTooltipModule in the same location.

Comment: Sam, feel free to make an edit indicating that module names (or import strategy) have changed.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this today, (as commented by Sam in the other response) I needed to add MatTooltipModule to my imports

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
...
imports: [
  ...
  MatTooltipModule,
  ...
]
...
}
```